# changing label class for radio button groups

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

below is a code snippet of radio button group using a bootstrap template.  But what I am trying to do is change the class portion of the radio button every time the option is toggled (i.e. radio button is checked the label class would be 'btn btn-primary' and if unchecked label class would be 'btn btn-default' ).  Anyone knows how to accomplish this?

```
<body>
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label class = "control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Gender</label>

        <div class = "col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div id = "gender" class = "btn-group" data-toggle = "buttons">
                <label class = "btn btn-default" data-toggle-active-class = "btn-primary" data-toggle-passive-class = "btn-default">
                    <input type = "radio" name = "gender" value = "male"> &nbsp; Male &nbsp;
                </label>

                <label class = "btn btn-primary" data-toggle-class = "btn-primary" data-toggle-passive-class = "btn-default">
                    <input type = "radio" name = "gender" value = "female"> Female
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
 $('input:radio').change(function(){
      var $self = $(this);
      if ($self.prop('checked')) {
      $('input[type=radio]').parent().removeClass('btn-primary');
         $self.parent().addClass('btn-primary');
      } else {
         $self.parent().removeClass('btn-default');
      }
   });
```

Here working fiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/3r602pcg/

Comment: thanks for the response to my query, sorry it took a while for me to respond new at this web development thingy so I could not respond sooner cause i needed to check out your answer....anyway, back to the topic.....your suggestion worked but it has a bug, if you notice on your jfiddle the intial button looses the border somewhat I think, it should have reverted to the btn-default class...any thoughts?

Comment: I figured out your bug and it worked fantastically...thanks so very much for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below:

```
$(function(){
    $(".checkbox-class").change(function() {
    $("#gender").toggleClass("show-hide", this.checked)
  }).change();
});​
```

Or alternatively you can try `addClass` and `removeClass` method using jQuery

Comment: thanks for the response to my query, sorry it took a while for me to respond new at this web development thingy so I could not respond sooner cause i needed to check out your answer....anyway, back to the topic.....tried your suggestion but sadly it didn't work nothing happens when i uncheck the radio button

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to accomplish this easily, use this at bottom-

```
$('input[type=radio]').each(function(){
     if($(this).prop('checked')){
       $(this).removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-primary');
     }else{
       $(this).removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
     }
 });
```

Comment: thanks for the response to my query, sorry it took a while for me to respond new at this web development thingy so I could not respond sooner cause i needed to check out your answer....anyway, back to the topic.....I tried what you suggested and even went far as to using your code but it was a negative, nothing happens even after I uncheck the radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Here is fixed answer from **Minal Chauhan**

```
  $('input:radio').change(function(){
      var $self = $(this);
      if ($self.prop('checked')) {
            $('input[type=radio]').parent().removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
            $self.parent().removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-primary');
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

the above replied js does not apply when you have multiple buttons. above javascript code would dis function working of other buttons.
so js for changing label class for radio button groups would be like

```
$('input:radio').change(function(){
  var $self = $(this);
  if ($self.prop('checked')) {
  $self.parent().siblings('label').removeClass('btn-primary');
     $self.parent().addClass('btn-primary');
  } else {
     $self.parent().removeClass('btn-default');
  }
```

});